# How to make a function pickable so that it can be minimized through the parallel version of scipy.optimize.differential_evolution

Tags: python, parallel-processing, minimize, scipy-optimize, differential-evolution

I need to minimize a function using the scipy implementation of differential evolution.
I'd like to exploit parallelism to speed up the computation and I tried setting workers=-1.

I get an error and searching I found that the problem is that the function that I'm trying to minimize is not pickable.
I need help to understand how to make it pickable.

The function to minimize works in the following way:

- A class object has an attribute vector, the observed data.
- One method of the class takes some parameters and compute an estimate of the vector.
- The function to minimize compute the mean square error between the vector and the computed estimate.

The pseudocode of the function could be something like that:

```
def function_to_minimize(self, parameters):
    true_vector = self.true_vector
    estimated_vector = self.estimate_vector(parameters)
    return mse(true_vector, estimated_vector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
class Objective(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.measured_data = data

    def __call__(self, parameters):
        # need to return a scalar value
        estimated_vector = self.estimate_vector(parameters)
        return np.sum(np.power(self.measured_data - estimated_vector, 2))

    def estimate_vector(parameters):
        # calculate what you expect to happen with the parameters
        pass
```

you should pass `Objective(data)` to `differential_evolution` as the function to minimize. On macOS and Windows that use `spawn` as the default way of creating new processes this function should be [defined in a file that is importable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods).